# File not reading

Tags: c, fopen

I am trying to run a simple test to read and print a file to console. I have my "main.c" file and "myfile.txt" in the same folder on my desktop (Mac). However, when running the program I receive "No such file or directory." I tried changing the address to everything I can think of... Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? My apologies I am new to this and have hit a wall.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * file;
    char str [256];
    
    file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    
    if (NULL == file)
    {
        perror("Error when opening file!");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(fgets(str, 10, file) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", &str);
    }
    
    fclose(file);
}
```

I was expecting to print the first 10 chars of the txt file into the console. Instead I received "No such file or directory."

Comment: Use the full pathname, unless running from a console with the file's folder as the current working directory.

Comment: Is the executable file being created in the same directory? How are you running the program? Is it through your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)? If that is the case, then I suggest that you run [`getcwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3p.html) to determine the current working directory, which is the directory in which files without a pathname must reside. Here is some example code: `char path[200]; printf( "%s\n", getcwd( path, sizeof path ) );` Note that you must `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: *Instead I received "No such file or directory."* This means there is no such file or directory *in the place the program is trying to find it*. For relative file paths like "myfile.txt", that place is called "current working directory" and it could be tricky to determine or set up if you are using GUI tools.

Comment: Most IDEs allow you to set the current working directory for a project when you run it through the IDE.